# jQuery: multiple "window.location.href" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am having getting multiple window location selectors to work. The result im looking for is a test alert popup. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using this in GreaseMonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        b
// @namespace   d
// @description b
// @include     *www.*
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function () 
{ if(   (!window.location.href("https://www.youtube.com") > -1)  
       & (!window.location.href("https://www.google.com") > -1)    
    )   
{   

alert("I am an alert box!");

}
});
```

Comment: href is NOT a method....

Comment: Also, waiting for the document to be ready is pretty much useless (the location is available even if the DOM isn't ready).

Comment: Why would it not be executed @MarcoBonelli? If the doc is ready it will fire immediately

Comment: @charlietfl true, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1) Error in conditional statement `&` should be `&&`

2) also you need to use `indexOf` to find index of desired uri in href:

```
  if((!window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") > -1)  
     && (!window.location.href.indexOf("https://www.google.com") > -1)    
  )
```

Comment: @computerguy: used `indexOf` ?

Comment: i used indexof, just wasnt sure if it applied to the domain url only, without /***

Comment: will && work if  i want to use more than one window.location url selectors with this code? Such as, 50 urls?

Comment: @computerguy 50 URLS seems like a bad design to check it like that... Horrible to maintain.

Comment: an idea of a more eligant design? I need them in a $(document).ready since my script will do many things, for specific sites.

Comment: Assuming you do not need IE support `["google.com","stackoverflow.com"].includes(window.location.host)`

Comment: @computerguy: yes it will.

Comment: not sure how I implement it into the script correctly, apologies

Comment: 1) you need to make array of 50 urls (say refURLs []) 2) then use `refURLs.includes(window.location.‌​href) `